# Description of hues in a diagram

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, image-identification

I am using different hues to illustrate the data in a diagram for my thesis, but I am not sure how to describe them. Which combination of words would be correct:

> Smoothed data are shown using **solid** / **strong** / **dark** colors and
>    unsmoothed data are shown using **light** / **soft** / **pale** colors.

[image: Smoothed and unsmoothed dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "dark" and "pale".

Comment: IMHO, "bright" is more usual antonym for "pale".

Comment: "bright" is about how much light there is, pale is about the intensity of hue. A sunrise could be both bright (lots of light) and pale (a clear sky, so not a lot of color to it).